# Show div background-image complete

Tags: html, css

I cant the the complete background-image of the div container. I want to see 100% of the height and 100% of the width of the picture. If i add the image as  tag in the html Code it work perfect, but i want to write over the image some headlines. I mean the background-image "header-sidebar" at sidebar.
Here is [my Page](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Site) + the Code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: black;
}

body{
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    height: 1500px;
}

section{
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 1230px;
    height: 100%;
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

article{
    background-color: #FBB9B7;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    
    float: left;
    
    padding: 20px;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

aside{
    background-color: #FBB9B7;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    
    float: right;
    
    padding: 20px;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.header-sidebar{
    background: url(http://www.drlaureen.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/headline-sidebar.png) no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <section>
            <article>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </article>
            <aside>
                
                
                <div class="header-sidebar">
                    Überschrift 1 
                </div> 
            </aside>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, its unclear to me...

Comment: do you mean the background of the body ? or the header sidebar ? these are the only 2 background images in the code I guess ?

Comment: not clear at all. Which div is the container? Where do yo have the bg image? If you mean the body, I can see that image without problems, so really no idea what you mean

Comment: The background of the "Header-sidebar"

Answer (score 0):

use `background-size:cover` in body instead of defining height and width

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your text, but I guess you want a full-screen background image, right?
Your image needs to resize, depending on the browser width.
It is better to load another (smaller) image for small screens.

```
body {
     background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
   }
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
  background: url(images/bg-small.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the background-size.

```
 background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit; For more refer to w3school.

 background-size:100% 100%;
```